# What technique could I use to I improve my image recognition?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

To improve my detection I've tried:

- All the methods `matchTemplate` allows for and found `TM_CCORR_NORMED` works best
- Setting both my template and my images to grayscale added a few %  to successful detections
- Cropping the template area down to only the area where the text is found

These methods have helped but I'm still getting a lot of incorrect matches.

Is there a more appropriate way to detect images I've linked here:
[Haystack Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khvzV.jpg)
[Needle Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL2ig.jpg)

For testing purposes I've been changing `1.jpg` to 2/3/4/5/6/7.jpg

Image 5.jpg is a good example to test as only one out of nine matches come back with a reliable match.

```
import glob
import cv2 as cv
import os

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

haystack = glob.glob(r"C:\stack\haystack\*.jpg")
needle = cv.imread("1.jpg", cv.IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_2)

for file in haystack:
    haystack = cv.imread(file, cv.IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_2)
    result = cv.matchTemplate(needle, haystack, cv.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(result)
    percentage_max_val = round(max_val*100, 2)
    print(percentage_max_val)

    cv.imshow("test", result)
    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: that looks like a bitmap font. matchTemplate, given such a template, should return a score array with clear peaks for those detections. the only issue you might have is how strong the peaks need to be to be true positives. -- I'd suggest `SQDIFF` rather than the other variants, and maybe avoid the "normed" variants in favor of calculating your own absolute thresholds (possible with a little math, or just eyeballing it). -- please prepare a [mre], including a few templates and a "haystack" image to run it on.

Comment: I should've said, they are .png, I made sure to check the values when going through the different methods and TM_CCORR_NORMED was a standout (I made sure to invert the values where needed for the method too). It works pretty well, but I'm wondering if there's next step/obvious improvement. I was looking into using something like canny but I think I'd need to convert both the haystack and the needle to do that and that feels like a lot when I've only just got this working (and it does work finally!)

Comment: my heuristic is that when someone mentions canny, they are, in most cases, about to dig their own grave. avoid it. it's like taking a hammer to the nail of a stubbed toe. wrong tool for the task (unless the task is the right one).

Comment: I'll add the few lines needed to make it work and templates. Thank you for the advice on canny, it just keeps coming up over and over.

Comment: I said bitmap font in contrast to "vector" font. vector fonts might shift their glyphs in subpixel increments. bitmap fonts have the advantage of always looking the same, pixel-wise. easier to locate using this kind of correlation (matchTemplate). -- PNG, really anything that is _not_ lossy compression (jpg), is a good idea with these things.

Comment: Updated with I think a MRE